# Can I use dynamic types in F#?

Tags: dynamic, f#, c#-4.0, ironpython

.net4.0

mytest.py

```
def Add (a, b):
    return a+b
```

I can use it in C# 4, like this:

```
        ScriptRuntime runtime = Python.CreateRuntime();
        dynamic script = runtime.UseFile("mytest.py");

        Console.WriteLine(script.Add(1, 3));
```

But, how can I use dynamic in F#?

```
open System
open Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
open IronPython.Hosting

let call a b=
    let runtime = Python.CreateRuntime()
    let script = runtime.UseFile("mytest.py")
    script.Add(a,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a module [FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/), on nuget that implements the dynamic operator using the dlr.  So That:

```
open System
open Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
open IronPython.Hosting
open EkonBenefits.FSharp.Dynamic

let call a b=
    let runtime = Python.CreateRuntime()
    let script = runtime.UseFile("mytest.py")
    script?Add(a,b)
```

It has several advantages over a lot of the snippets out there.

- Performance it uses [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) for the dlr call and Dynamitey implements caching of the callsites and is a PCL library
- Handles methods that return void, you'd get a binding exception if you didn't discard results of those when the binder was setup.
- The dlr handles the case of calling a delegate return by a function automatically, impromptu fsharp will also allow you to do the same with an FSharpFunc
- Adds an !? prefix operator to handle invoking directly dynamic objects and functions you don't have the type at runtime.

  It's open source, Apache license, you can look at the [implementation](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/blob/master/FSharp.Dynamic/Dynamic.fs) and it includes unit test [example cases](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/blob/master/Tests/Library1.fs).